# How to recognize preamble in on-off keyed waveform using Java

Tags: java, signal-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to parse a captured waveform using Java to recognize a preamble with a cadence of high and low states (each nominally 5ms/240 samples long), concluding with a 20ms high, and determine the offset of the first 'negative' sample after the preamble's final sample.

You can assume the data is an array of signed integers. I could capture in a different format (unsigned bytes, floats/doubles, etc) if it made things easier.

The method **does not** have to be realtime or single-pass/stream-friendly. Inhaling the whole waveform into an array, making copies of it to non-destructively apply different software filters and experiment with multiple approaches at runtime, etc, is all OK. You can safely assume it's running on a computer with gigabytes of RAM and a hefty multi-core desktop CPU.

Here's an example of the waveform I'm trying to interpret. The preamble is at the start (followed by MFM-encoded bits, but that's a problem for a future question... I'm trying to keep this question as tightly-focused as possible and limit its scope to just the preamble's recognition).

In real life, there could potentially be up to ~20,000-40,000 samples with random noise prior to the preamble's start.

- This particular preamble has six high-low pulses that all showed up clearly in my test waveform, but in real life, the preamble would probably be longer, and it's entirely possible that the first few could be mangled or missing.
- If changes to the preamble format would make the task of recognition and synchronization easier, I can easily make them.

[image]

At the moment, I'm just (stupidly) plowing through it looking for 950-970 'high' samples in a row, then examining the samples 120, 360, 600, and 840 before it to confirm that they're low, high, low, and high (ignoring the very real possibility of noise, drop-out, or just an anomalous value that looks correct amidst a sea of wrong ones).

**I know there *has* to be a better way that probably involves filtering... but I don't know what it *is*, and want to find out.**

Ideally, I'd like to be able to intelligently recognize the preamble, even if it's not completely noise-free. Abstracting it a bit, let's say I'd like to be able to recognize a preamble with 4+ high/low periods, followed by a burst of random noise that concludes with a detectable high at a plausible offset, a 5ms low, and the 20ms high end marker.

I'd also like to be able to use the preamble to discern the sender's exact timing. Nominally, each preamble-pulse is high for 5ms/240 samples and low for 5ms/240 samples... but it's obviously possible that if the sender's and receiver's clocks aren't precisely identical, the receiver might perceive the pulses as being 239, 238, 241, 242, or some other close-but-not-quite-240 stride apart.

So... what's a **good** way to accomplish preamble-recognition and recover the sender's clock?

Comment: You could start by low-pass filtering it using a simple IIR filter (e.g. `flt += (signal - flt)*0.1`), then differentiating the signal to find the vertical jumps. Those jumps would be spread by the filter so you have to employ a hysteresis detector. Whenever the detector goes high, you can store the timestamp to determine the timing.